# Error run current project after flutter upgrade v3.13

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following error run project in my vscode debug console after flutter upgrade v3.13:

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\DIMAS\FlutterCode\skip\.dart_tool\flutter_build\35269fa8986c9ee7a9c97697217003ec\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\DIMAS\FlutterCode\skip\.dart_tool\flutter_build\35269fa8986c9ee7a9c97697217003ec\kernel_snapshot.d
Error: Could not resolve the package 'characters' in 'package:characters/characters.dart'.
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'package:characters/characters.dart'
import 'package:characters/characters.dart';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/widgets.dart:18:1: Error: Not found: 'package:characters/characters.dart'
export 'package:characters/characters.dart';
^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'package:characters/characters.dart'
import 'package:characters/characters.dart';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'package:characters/characters.dart'
import 'package:characters/characters.dart';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
               ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart:822:61: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
  int get _currentLength => _effectiveController.value.text.characters.length;
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart:824:118: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
  bool get _hasIntrinsicError => widget.maxLength != null && widget.maxLength > 0 && _effectiveController.value.text.characters.length > widget.maxLength;
                                                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:244:64: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
       assert(obscuringCharacter != null && obscuringCharacter.characters.length == 1),
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:361:35: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
    assert(value != null && value.characters.length == 1);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:567:11: Error: 'Characters' isn't a type.
    final Characters remaining = string.characters.skipWhile((String currentString) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:567:41: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
    final Characters remaining = string.characters.skipWhile((String currentString) {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:600:47: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
    for (final String currentString in string.characters) {
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/editable.dart:602:40: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
          !_isWhitespace(currentString.characters.first.toString().codeUnitAt(0))) {
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:167:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30: Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class 'PictureStreamCompleter'.
 - 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringShort'.
      ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(description);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart:355:11: Error: 'CharacterRange' isn't a type.
    final CharacterRange iterator = CharacterRange(value.text);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart:355:37: Error: Method not found: 'CharacterRange'.
    final CharacterRange iterator = CharacterRange(value.text);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart:356:20: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
    if (value.text.characters.length > maxLength) {
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart:375:61: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
    if (maxLength != null && maxLength > 0 && newValue.text.characters.length > maxLength) {
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart:378:25: Error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'characters'.
      if (oldValue.text.characters.length == maxLength) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^

Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untransla
table-uri:package%3Acharacters%2Fcharacters.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
[38;5;248m#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri  (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)[39;49m

[38;5;248m#1      asFileUri  (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)[39;49m
[38;5;248m#2      writeDepfile  (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:853:21)[39;49m
<asynchronous suspen
sion>
[38;5;248m#3      FrontendCompiler.compile  (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:574:15)[39;49m
[38;5;244m<asynchronous suspension>[39;49m
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (packa
ge:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22)
[38;5;248m#5      starter  (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:182:27)[39;49m

#6      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flut
ter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:9:30)
[38;5;244m#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure>  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)[39;49m
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl
._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

its seems missing character.dart and some gradle stuff, but i couldn't find exact problem and answer for now on google,

But if i make and run a new project it doesn't have any error, herewith my pubspec.yaml (i've compared old & new project pubspec.yaml there is no significant different exept for additional package):
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you’re missing characters package in your pubspec.yaml.

Make sure it is there and your pubspec is formatted properly. And run `flutter pub get` again.

If this fails, you should run `flutter pub cache repair`

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue.

In pubspec.yaml just execute `flutter pub get` and `flutter pub upgrade`.

Then in the root directory terminal execute `flutter clean` and it will run without problems.

Answer (score 4):

I have had similar issue on my flutter application after I updated the flutter SDK.

What solved my issue were to do the following.

Open a terminal (CMD) navigate to your flutter project, where the pubspec.yaml is. Run the following commands:

**Solution**

> `flutter pub get`
>
> `flutter pub upgrade`
>
> After that if you still have issues you can run the `flutter pub cache repair`, however the
>
> `flutter clean`
>
> did the trick for me and fixed the issue.
>
> I restarted both visual studio and the AVD virtual device, to be sure
> to have a fresh restart.

**What tools and software I use:**

Visual Studio Code 1.47.3

Android Studio 4.0.1 (Android Virtual Device)

Flutter 1.20.1 (Release date 6.8.2020)

Dart 2.9.0

Answer (score 2):

after refresh the `flutter pub get`, i've had error SVG problem and i update `flutter_svg: ^0.17.4` to `flutter_svg: ^0.18.0` it solved SVG problem,

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into this issue a couple times after running `flutter upgrade` on a new flutter release. In my case, the solution had nothing to do with the error. Just outdated dependencies.

I first did `flutter clean` (IntelliJ/Android Studio from the tools>Flutter>Flutter clean.)

Updated my `pubspec.yaml` dependencies to their latest version and ran `flutter pub upgrade`

Finished! Now you should be able to build and run

Answer (score 0):

try in terminal

```
$     flutter clean
```

after

```
$     flutter doctor
```

that should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, after deleting the `.dart_tool` directory/folder and running the application again, the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Many people are getting this as the kotlin version and build SDK versions are not in line with each other. just do as follow. one can clean this by only `flutter pub upgrade` after `flutter pub cache repair` but once for all I will suggest to follow as below.

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `flutter pub cache repair`
4. `flutter pub upgrade`

done! Happy Coding.